# How to add a boolean property to a JSON token

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON which represents settings for an application.  A simplified example is shown below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_settings": {
      "jbofmngeodhmdlnicmlnfhjmmbdbcokh": {
        "title": "app 1",
        "description": "desc 1",
        "custom_app_setting_stored_below": "asd",
        "cust1": 3,
        "cust2": false
      },
      "esghmzlnxcfpnrkbokmvgtjmcaknysdb": {
        "title": "app 2",
        "description": "desc 2",
        "custom_app_setting_stored_below": "asd",
        "cust8": 12,
        "cust10": "11/25/2013",
        "cust11": "nothing",
        "cust12": true,
        "cust13": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The application can have extensions (represented in the settings by the long random strings of letters), and each extension can have its own custom settings beneath it.

I can manually blacklist an extension by adding a "blacklist" property for an extension and setting it to true.  This will prevent the extension from being loaded by the application.

Here's an example of a blacklisted extension:

```
  "jbofmngeodhmdlnicmlnfhjmmbdbcokh": {
    "title": "app 1",
    "description": "desc 1",
    "custom_app_setting_stored_below": "asd",
    "cust1": 3,
    "cust2": false,
    "icons": {
      "128": "text21456.gif",
      "16": "text21456.gif",
      "48": "text21456.gif"
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "path": "plugins/ApiPlugin.dll",
        "public": true
      },
      {
        "path": "plugins/mp.dll",
        "public": true
      },
      {
        "path": "plugins/Plugin.dll",
        "public": true
      }
    ],
    "blacklist": true
  }
```

Now I want to be able to blacklist an extension programmatically.
In C#, I'm  searching for a specific extension like this:

```
var data = json["data"];
var app_settings = data["app_settings"];
var a = app_settings.Children().ToList();
foreach (var b in a)
{
    if (b.ToString().ToLower().Contains("extensionname"))
    {
        JToken ext = b;

        // need to add blacklist property here
    }
}
```

So for example, if the search matches, I might have something like this in `ext`:

```
"jbofmngeodhmdlnicmlnfhjmmbdbcokh": {
    "custom_extension_property_1": "value 1",
    "custom_extension_property_2": "value 2"
}
```

How do I add a "blacklist" boolean property in those extension settings so it will look like this?

```
"jbofmngeodhmdlnicmlnfhjmmbdbcokh": {
    "custom_extension_property_1": "value 1",
    "custom_extension_property_2": "value 2",
    "blacklist": true
}
```

I don't think this will work:

```
bool blacklist = true;
ext.AddAfterSelf(blacklist);
```

or this:

```
someobject o = new someobject() {
   blacklist = true;
};
ext.AddAfterSelf(o);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how can I forgot about that. sorry.
updating it now

Comment: updated and the question is located below the post

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you're trying to find a particular extension by its title, and then add a "blacklist" property to that extension's settings if the title is found.  You can do that like this:

```
string extensionNameToBlacklist = "app 1";

var data = json["data"];
var app_settings = data["app_settings"];

foreach (JProperty extensionProperty in app_settings)
{
    JObject extensionObject = (JObject)extensionProperty.Value;
    if ((string)extensionObject["title"] == extensionNameToBlacklist)
    {
        extensionObject.Add("blacklist", true);
    } 
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tESgmB

I think the part you were missing is that [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is just a base class for more specific token classes like [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and [`JProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm).  Sometimes you have to cast the `JToken` to be able to access methods and properties that are specific to that class, like the [`Add`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm) method on `JObject`.  (If you have a token and you don't know what kind it is, you can check its [`Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) property to find out.)